# Passing @(at sign)-variables to MySQL

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, variables, ado.net

I am fairly new to VB.NET so I research alot when I run into bugs. Problem is I cannot find a solution to this, or anything remotely dealing with it.

I am developing software to connect to a remote mysql server, run a query, and come back with a dataset. I have run this query against the server through a mysql prompt and have received a result successfully. But when i try to run this query from my app, I get an object reference error.

Through debugging I have found that the @ character used for variables in sql strings, is causing the problem in my code, but i cannot find a way to pass this query to the server without visual studio throwing errors. Every answer to the use of variables that I have found, suggests specifically stipulating the variable values in my code, which I do not want to do.

Here is a bit of my code and my query:

```
Dim mysqlCon As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Server=" & arrArgs & ";Database=DBNAME;Uid=USER;Pwd=PASS;allow zero datetime=true;")
Dim mysqlString As String = "set @from_scanner = '" & code & "'; set @code='', @altbarcode='', @qty='1', @price='',@Altprice='0', @date_start='',@date_end='',@disc_price='0',@description='', @altdescription=''; set @from_scanner=if(left(@from_scanner,2)='FF',trim(substring(@from_Scanner,3,13)),trim(substring(@from_Scanner,2,13))); select code, altbarcode,description, qty, price into @code, @altbarcode,@altdescription, @qty, @Altprice from altbar where altbarcode=@from_scanner; set @code=if(@code='',@from_Scanner,@code); select disc_price, date_end into @disc_price, @date_end from plu where (code=trim(left(@code,12)) or def_barcode=@code) and current_date between date_start and date_end and disc_price<>price and disc_price<>0; select price, description into @price, @description from plu where code=trim(left(@code,12)) or def_barcode=@code; set @price=if(ifnull(@disc_price,0)=0 or @disc_price='', @price,@disc_price); set @price=if(@qty>1 and @Altprice > 0, @Altprice, @price*@qty); set @description=if(@altdescription<>'', @Altdescription, @description); select @code, format(@price,2) Price, @description,@date_end;"
Dim mysqlCom As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(mysqlstring, mysqlCon)
Dim mysqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim mysqlData As New DataSet

mysqlCon.Open()

mysqlAdapter.SelectCommand = mysqlCom
mysqlAdapter.Fill(mysqlData, "tblDBData")
```

So what I really need to know is how to pass this query on to the mysql server without causing problems in VB.

Answer (score 2):

The field names from the query itself shouldn't have the @ in them.  Only the variables you are replacing with values.  I will give you a very simple sql query to updatea row from a table, as an example:

```
Dim sqlString as String = "UPDATE tableName SET Disc_Price=@Price WHERE Code=@Code"
```

In this case tableName is the name of your table, Disc_Price is a column Name, Code is a Column Name.  It will update the value in the Disc_Price field to whatever you tell it the value for @Price is, for the row or rows that match @Code in the Code Field.

Then you set up the command and define the query parameters:

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sqlString, mysqlConn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", 1.25)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code",WhateverCodeHere)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Make sure only your parameters/sql variables in the query have the @ and you should be fine.

I also noticed in your string, that the table name and UPDATE key word weren't in the query string with your SET.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response.

Comment: My problem is that the only information I am passing to the server is the item code from the scanner, and I send this through the VB variable "code". 
I have created mysql variables in the query because the query itself does all the work and assigns/reassigns the mysql variables while executing the query against the database. In this way the mysql server does all the work and just provides a single record to VB as a dataset. 
I do not want to set the variable values in VB. I want to pass variable containers to mysql and have the query fill in the values.

Comment: I see what you mean now.  Unfortunately, I think you are stuck.  I am pretty certain that in that case you would have to actually replace the sql variables with the queries in your queryString in the code.  Sorry I wasn't of more help :(